# JavaScript TypeError with arrays and integers

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, random, undefined

So, I was having this problem with arrays in JavaScript.
I initialized some variables as shown here:

```
var world = new Array;
var monsters = new Array;
var items = new Array;
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
```

and tried to run this code on it:

```
            while (y <= 49) { //generate world
                world[x][y] = parseInt(Math.floor(Math.random()*2)); //0 = flatland, 1 = desert, 2 = mountain, 3 = swamp
                x++;
                if (x >= 49) {
                    x = 0;
                    y++;
                }
            }
            x = 0;
            y = 0;
```

but I get presented with this error: 
**"TypeError: can't convert undefined to object"**
on the **Math.random()** line.
I've tried everything I can think of, but it still throws that error.
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @spng453 It's generally accepted that using the literal array notation `[]` is better than using `new Array()`, precisely because it is so error-prone.

Comment: @Shmiddty: `new Array` and `new Array()` are both fine.

Comment: And `world[x]` is undefined, not an `array`, so `world[x][y]` is likely `undefined[y]` which will fail.

Comment: Ok, it makes sense now. I did have new Array(), but I read somewhere that it might help to just say new Array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`world[x][y]` is not initialized. That's the problem. You need to intialize below the `while` statement

```
while (y <= 49) {
    world[x] = new Array(); //add this
```

Answer (score 1):

`world[x]` is not an array so you get an error when trying to assign a value to `world[x][y]`, your method of filling the array seems strange to me, I'd do it this way

```
world = [];
for (x = 0; x <= 49; x++) { //generate world
    world[x] = [];
    for (y = 0; y <= 49; y++){
        world[x][y] = parseInt(Math.floor(Math.random()*2)); //0 = flatland, 1 = desert, 2 = mountain, 3 = swamp
    }
}
x = 0;
y = 0;
```

Comment: Hmm, I understand what you are saying with the for statements but for me, it is easier to read nested while statements.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `()`. World must be defined as a two dimensional array `world[x] = new Array();` Using the [] notation is more convenient.